# Remove from List<T> based on sub-string match

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, collections, filtering

```
sampleList.RemoveAll(a=>a.reference.Contains("123"));
```

This line of code does not remove any item from the list whereas

```
sampleList.RemoveAll(a=>!a.reference.Contains("123"));
```

removes all the items.

I have currently resorted to making another list and going through a for loop and adding stuff to the second list, but I dont really like this approach.

Is there a cleaner way to achieve what I am trying ?

Comment: Are you sure you have items that contain the string "123" in the `reference`?

Comment: Latter one should not compile at all, have you provided rigth code snippet?

Comment: Works for me: http://rextester.com/TPAQW81340

Comment: @sll ya you were right it , corrected it

Comment: Ok please provide minimum of sample data you are using to reproduce this issue

Comment: Is "reference" a string?

Comment: Feeling really stupid right now as it works for me too , must have missed something the first time i wrote the code. @Jamiec thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the second example "removes all the items" and the first removes none, leads me to conclude that none of the item's `reference` property in the list contains the string "123".

Elementry my dear watson ;)

Comment: was apparently removing something else instead of reference  :|

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your `sampleList` contains no elements containing "123". This is proven by the fact that the first attempt removes nothing, and the second attempt (which is the reverse of the first) removes everything.

Here is a sample console application I wrote to test out what I think your trying to achieve, and it works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> sampleList = new List<string>(new string[]
    {
        "Some String", "Some Other String", "Hello World", "123456789", "987654123"
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Items:");
    foreach (string item in sampleList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nRemoving items containing \"123\"...");

    int itemsRemoved = sampleList.RemoveAll(str => str.Contains("123"));
    Console.WriteLine("Removed {0} items.", itemsRemoved);

    Console.WriteLine("\nItems:");
    foreach (string item in sampleList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Start by checking the values of the items in your collection. Once you've made sure the values contain what they should, check the return value of `RemoveAll(...)` to check the right number of elements have been removed.